# Python Pyaudio, How to choose a specific input on audio interface for recording?

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, recording

In an example below, seems like that I can choose a correct audio device(by index) and can spec NUMBER of recorded channels, but I can't choose the EXACT (say channel number 7) channel.
My system is Mac and I have external audio interface with 18 inputs and 18 outputs.

```
stream_in = pa.open(
    rate=48000,
    channels=2,
    format=pyaudio.paInt16,
    input=True,                   # input stream flag
    input_device_index=4,         # input device index
    frames_per_buffer=1024,

)
```

there is other parameter called

input_host_api_specific_stream_info –
Specifies a host API specific stream information data structure for input.
See PaMacCoreStreamInfo.

but that's something I'm generally lost into.

Comment: did you fix that please ?